# Not getting desired output when trying to add values to a map Flutter

Tags: flutter, hashmap, flutter-test

I have a map named _body to which I'm trying to add values dynamically using

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    _body.addAll({
            'receiver_details': {

              '[$i]': {
                "receiver_name": "$receiver_name",
              }
    }
}
)
}
```

the desired output would be

```
{receiver_details: {[0]: {receiver_name: abc}},[1]: {receiver_name: vhhh}}}
```

but all I'm getting is

```
{receiver_details: [1]: {receiver_name: vhhh}}}
```

Only the last index is being added and the rest are getting overwritten. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
_body['receiver_details'] = {};
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  _body['receiver_details']['[$i]'] = {
        "receiver_name": "$receiver_name",
  };
}
```